# How to use cleditor rich textarea in active admin in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

I have Post table with title and content attributes. I am using [cleditor](https://github.com/cleditor/cleditor) for rich textarea on content attributes. By using `<%= raw post.content %>` I am showing the post content so that It can safe by HTML tags. Now I am using [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) for Admin support.

Now My problem is in Admin Panel. It showing content with HTML tags. How can I use raw function in active admin? How can i use rich text so that EDIT perform correctly by admin? Please give me some pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at this one it may solve your problem.
[Active Admin Editor](https://github.com/ejholmes/active_admin_editor)

in view you can use safe_html
(raw) by visiting this [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thanks It works like a charm! :) but I have another issue, Why In view it showing content with HTML tags. How to use raw function in that one??

Comment: :-)
ok i will look at this one.

Comment: i updated my answer , look at this one, it will solve all your problem. :-)